# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL10 android studio

Tags: java, android, exception, noclassdeffounderror

i try to run a code of application game 3D but the application don't work in my device and in onglet 'android Monitor' in android studio i have this fatal exception :

> 07-22 15:40:29.015 22222-22245/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4132
>                                                      Process: com.anisbulbul.car.race, PID: 22222
>                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL10
>                                                          at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.setupGL(AndroidGraphics.java:301)
>                                                          at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceCreated(AndroidGraphics.java:346)
>                                                          at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1500)
>                                                          at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)

and this is the code of the activity

```
 // Copyright:           2015, anisbulbul
// Home page:           http://www.codecanyon.net/user/anisbulbul

package com.anisbulbul.car.race;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.anisbulbul.car.race.assets.GameAssets;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements
        GameHelper.GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {

    protected AdView adViewMain;
    private GameHelper gameHelper;
    protected View gameView;
    AdView adView;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER = "ca-app-pub-8606268298440779/7190429247";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL = "ca-app-pub-8606268298440779/5713696049";

    private static final String MORE_APPS_URL = "http://codecanyon.net/user/anisbulbul/portfolio";
    private static boolean IS_ADMOB_ACTIVE = true;
    private static boolean DEBUG = false;
    private static boolean IS_PLAY_SERVICE_ACTIVE = true;
    private static String GOOGLE_PLAY_URL;
    private static String FACEBOOK_SHARE_URL;
    private static String TWITTER_SHARE_URL;
    private static String GOOGLE_PLUS_SHARE_URL;
    private static String BLOG_URL;

    @Override
    public String[] getAchievmentIDs() {
        String achievmentIDs[] = {
                getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_bigginer),
                getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_starter_good),
                getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_race_cup_2),
                getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_after_death),
                getResources().getString(R.string.achievement_in_the_last_station) };

        return achievmentIDs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    private AdView createAdView() {
        this.adViewMain = new AdView(this);
        this.adViewMain.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        this.adViewMain.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
        this.adViewMain.setId(12345);
        LayoutParams var1 = new LayoutParams(-1, -2);
        var1.addRule(12, -1);
        var1.addRule(14, -1);
        this.adViewMain.setLayoutParams(var1);
        this.adViewMain.setBackgroundColor(-16777216);
        return this.adViewMain;
    }

    private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration var1) {
        this.gameView = this.initializeForView(new CarRace3D(this), var1);
        LayoutParams var2 = new LayoutParams(-1, -2);
        var2.addRule(10, -1);
        var2.addRule(14, -1);
        var2.addRule(2, this.adViewMain.getId());
        this.gameView.setLayoutParams(var2);
        return this.gameView;
    }

    private void startAdvertising(AdView var1) {
        var1.loadAd((new AdRequest.Builder()).build());
    }

    @Override
    public void faceBookPost(String fbMessage) {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent
                .putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "https://facebook.com/share?url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName()+"&title="+fbMessage);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        this.startActivity(sendIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void googlePlusPost(String gplusMessage) {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent
                .putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName()+"&title="+gplusMessage);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        this.startActivity(sendIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void twitterPost(String twMessage) {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent
                .putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName()+"&related=codecanyon.net&text=i got high score"+twMessage);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        this.startActivity(sendIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
        if (this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            this.startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements
                    .getAchievementsIntent(this.gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardHighScoreGPGS() {
        if (this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            this.startActivityForResult(
                    Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                            this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                            this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score_race)),
                    100);
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardTrophyGPGS() {
        if (this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            this.startActivityForResult(
                    Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(
                            this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                            this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_race_trophy)),
                    100);
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void getAllLeaderboardGPGS() {
        if (this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
            this.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards
                    .getAllLeaderboardsIntent(this.gameHelper.getApiClient()),
                    1);
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return this.gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        if(IS_PLAY_SERVICE_ACTIVE){
            try {
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        MainActivity.this.gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception var2) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int var1, int var2, Intent var3) {
        super.onActivityResult(var1, var2, var3);
        this.gameHelper.onActivityResult(var1, var2, var3);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        GameAssets.isGamePause = true;
        if (GameAssets.isGameSound) {
            GameAssets.raceMusic.pause();
            GameAssets.accidentMusic.pause();
            GameAssets.moveMusic.pause();
        }

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(MainActivity.this);

        LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        dialogLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(R.string.back_option_text);
        textView.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
        dialogLayout.addView(textView);

        Button resumeButton = new Button(this);
        resumeButton.setText("Resume");
        resumeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(resumeButton);

        Button moreGamesApps = new Button(this);
        moreGamesApps.setText("More Games & Apps");
        moreGamesApps.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(MORE_APPS_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(moreGamesApps);

        Button rateButton = new Button(this);
        rateButton.setText("Rate Game");
        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(GOOGLE_PLAY_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(rateButton);

        Button facebookButton = new Button(this);
        facebookButton.setText("Facebook");
        facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(FACEBOOK_SHARE_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(facebookButton);

        Button twitterButton = new Button(this);
        twitterButton.setText("Twitter");
        twitterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(TWITTER_SHARE_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(twitterButton);

        Button googlePlusButton = new Button(this);
        googlePlusButton.setText("Google Plus");
        googlePlusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(GOOGLE_PLUS_SHARE_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(googlePlusButton);

        Button blogButton = new Button(this);
        blogButton.setText("Blog");
        blogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(BLOG_URL)));
                dialog.dismiss();
                GameAssets.isGamePause = false;
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(blogButton);

        Button quitButton = new Button(this);
        quitButton.setText("Quit");
        quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialogLayout.addView(quitButton);

        scrollView.addView(dialogLayout);
        dialog.setContentView(scrollView);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,
                R.drawable.icon);

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
        super.onCreate(var1);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(128);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = true;
        cfg.useCompass = false;

        FACEBOOK_SHARE_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?display=popup&u=http%3A%2F%2Fcodecanyon.net%2Fitem%2Frecorder-and-equalizer-player-with-effect%2F9904887%3Futm_source%3Dsharefb";
        GOOGLE_PLAY_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id="
                + getPackageName();
        TWITTER_SHARE_URL = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check+out+%27Recorder+and+Equalizer+Player+with+Effect%27+on+%23EnvatoMarket+%23codecanyon&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodecanyon.net%2Fitem%2Frecorder-and-equalizer-player-with-effect%2F9904887%3Futm_source%3Dsharetw";
        GOOGLE_PLUS_SHARE_URL = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodecanyon.net%2Fitem%2Frecorder-and-equalizer-player-with-effect%2F9904887%3Futm_source%3Dsharegp";
        BLOG_URL = "http://anisbulbul.blogspot.com/";

        this.requestWindowFeature(1);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
        this.getWindow().clearFlags(2048);

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-1, -1));

        adView = this.createAdView();
        // layout.addView(adView);
        layout.addView(this.createGameView(cfg));

        this.setContentView(layout);
        this.startAdvertising(adView);

        this.interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        this.interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if(DEBUG){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Finished Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                if(DEBUG){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Closed Interstitial",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        if (this.gameHelper == null) {
            this.gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, 1);
            this.gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
        }

        this.gameHelper.setup(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(IS_PLAY_SERVICE_ACTIVE){
            this.gameHelper.onStart(this);          
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(IS_PLAY_SERVICE_ACTIVE){
            this.gameHelper.onStop();           
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void openUri(String uri) {
        this.startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri
                .parse(uri)));
    }

    @Override
    public void quitApplication() {

    }


    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(long score) {

        if(this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()){
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                    this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score_race), score);       
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitTrophyGPGS(long score) {

        if(this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()){
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                    this.getString(R.string.leaderboard_race_trophy), score);       
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
        if(this.gameHelper.isSignedIn()){
            Games.Achievements
            .unlock(this.gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);         
        } else if (!this.gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
            this.loginGPGS();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showRated() {

        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                            + getPackageName())));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void showShare() {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " Brain Puzzle Game "
                + " Visit: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                + getPackageName());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }

    public void addLayout() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        layout.addView(adView);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
        if (IS_ADMOB_ACTIVE) {

            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        addLayout();

                        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                            interstitialAd.show();

                            if(DEBUG){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Showing Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } else {
                            AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                    .build();
                            interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);

                            if(DEBUG){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Loading Interstitial", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }

}
```

build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anisbulbul.car.race"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':_3DCarRace')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
    //compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android-sources.jar')
    //compile files('libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
    //compile "com.android.support:support-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.deadpan-gamez:libGdx-game-common:1.22'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

}
```

i try to fix it but no solution

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From a quick glace, it looks like you're missing some build path entry. Could you share what fixes you've tried?

Comment: build path entry ? can you give me some more informations please and i tried to verified if all libraries are in the libs folder and if called in the dependencies that's all  !!

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of your build.gradle file?

Comment: @Christine i add it in the description of the question and thinks for your help